# JQuery using THIS as a .on [selector]

Tags: php, jquery, this

**Hi**,
So i've got this code:

```
$(document).on('click', ".buttonSelectAllOpt", function () {
    alert(this.attr("id"));
});
```

and PHP:

```
$iii=1
while([...]){
echo "<span class=\"buttonSelectAllOpt\" id=\"buttonSelectAllOpt$iii\">Some text</span>";
$iii++;
}
```

I want THIS to be .buttonSelectAllOpt, but
it seems that THIS reffers to document, and not to selector.
Do You know if I can somehow call the selector?

Comment: You should not be registering a click event on your entire document.  This means that anytime something is clicked in the entire document, your event will be fired.  Instead just do `$('a.buttonSelectAllOpt').on('click', function() {` etc...

Comment: @user1477388 You didn't read the post, or you don't understand arguments of the function; the second argument means: select only items with class="buttonSelectAllOpt"

Comment: I understand how it works.  I am saying instead of setting the event on the document, you should do like `$('a.buttonSelectAllOpt').on('click', function() {` because it's more efficient.  Have you seen the jQuery source code?  https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/event.js

Comment: You see, it won't work, because buttonSelectAllOpt is loading through ajax. Jquery loads selector only when the page is loaded, and .on changes it dynamically, as far as i'm concerned

Comment: On should be dynamic as it was implemented to replace `.live()` I believe.  However, should you need to re-register the event handler, you can always do so simply by placing it in a function and then calling the function on the complete of your AJAX.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this` in your example will refer to the `.buttonSelectAllOpt` element which was clicked, however you need to wrap it in a jQuery object to access the `attr()` method. Try this:

```
$(document).on('click', ".buttonSelectAllOpt", function () {
    alert($(this).attr("id"));
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/b5cd61y4/)

Comment: thanks! it worked.
I didn't know i can use `$(this)` ,  i thought i could only use this ;)

Answer (score 1):

`this` will refer to the item that was selected, so try selecting the actual element:

```
$('.buttonSelectAllOpt').click(function () {
    alert($(this).attr("id"));
});
```

Also note that `.click` is a preferred shorthand for `.on('click')`. Attaching the event to the actual object (instead of the document) is also faster.

See this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wtw6q6uo/).

Comment: Note that the OP is using a delegated event handler, and also that DOMElements do not have an `attr()` method.

Comment: I use ajax to add this divs, so i have to use .on

Comment: Ahh ok. I suppose that makes sense, then.

Answer (score 0):

Use either `this.id` or `$(this).attr('id')`. Inside event handlers, `this` is a DOM element, so you can access its properties directly. If you want to use the jQuery `.attr()` method, you need to wrap it in a jQuery object.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative answer so that you don't need to register an event with the document itself...

Try creating a method like this:

```
var initBtnHandler = function () {
    $('a.buttonSelectAllOpt').on('click', function() {
        alert($(this).attr('id'));
    });
}
```

Then, on the complete of your AJAX, simply re-register the event by calling the function:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'yourUrl',
    type: 'post',
    success: function () {
        // do something
    },
    complete: function() {
        initBtnHandler();
    }
});
```

Now, your new items will be registered with the event handler.

Comment: Oh, that's an idea, but it does the same, so there is no need to change my code